# How to convert nifti file to AFNI file?

Tags: matlab

I want to know how to convert a NIFTI file to an AFNI file (.HEAD/BRIK).

Comment: Did you check NiBabel? http://nipy.org/nibabel/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `3dcopy`:

`3dcopy myfile.nii myfile`

will create `myfile+tlrc.HEAD` and `myfile+tlrc.BRIK`

(AFNI can handle nifti files file, though, without them needing to be in HEAD/BRIK format).